# Can not import google.cloud module in python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip

I am following [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/01/powerful-image-analysis-google-cloud-vision-python/) article trying to make my Python script read labels related to an image using [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). The problem is that I am getting this error when trying to include a reference to **vision** from google.cloud module.

```
import io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

The error that I am getting says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

This is weird because when I do:

```
$ pip show google-cloud
```

I can see it is there and its files are located at:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_cloud-0.34.0.dist-info/*
```

Except for that, when I do **pip freeze** in my working folder I can see them both that I need available:

```
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-vision==0.33.0
```

I am now wondering what could be the reason for not being able to see include this module in my Python script.

Answer (score 1):

The [`google-cloud`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/) package is deprecated, you should uninstall it and install [`google-cloud-vision`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-vision/) instead.

Comment: I already did that but after 'pip install google-cloud-vision' I still can not see 'google-cloud' module in 'pip freeze' and of course I am still receiving the same error in my script.

Comment: Can you try using a newer version of `google-cloud-vision`?

Comment: If I don't explicitly specify a version it is downloading the latest one.

Answer (score -1):

This link might provide some assistance:

https://cloud.google.com/python/

Edited

upon looking into it further, I was able to do the following:

```
pip install google-cloud-vision
```

and import everything with:

```
import io
import os
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

Maybe try uninstalling the package through pip and reinstalling it with the above?

Comment: I am not targeting the storage APIs. I want to use the vision api as described in the Analyze images with Cloud Vision API section of the link you've added.

Comment: Editted, seemed like it worked for me, could you try uninstalling it through pip and reinstalling it again?  Also, when you're installing it via pip, are you running cmd in administrative mode?